# Hide all posts by an author

Tags: categories, author

We have a category called "Tech", and want to hide posts from a specific author on this page.

For example, John Smith's posts do not show in Tech category, or any category for that matter, even search.

How could I do this? I don't want to hide the author name, I want to completely hide all posts by author X from the search, category, taxonomy pages etc.

Thank you

Comment: How are you listing the categories currently? `get_categories`? `get_terms`?

Comment: I've done it now, cant post answer yet though. Basically a function for "pre_get_posts" which goes if is_category: $query->set( 'author', '-author_id' );

Answer (score 0):

A filter on `pre_get_posts` should do it.

```
function hide_author_wpse_138491($qry) {
  $exc = 123;
  if (
    !is_admin()
    && !is_singular()
  ) {
    $qry->set('author','-'.$exc);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','hide_author_wpse_138491');
```

This should exclude results from the author with ID = 123 on all front end pages except for "single" pages, which sound like what you are aiming for-- ie, to "completely hide all posts by author X from the search, category, taxonomy pages etc."